# Parsing Html Page with Dart

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I m trying to parse the following entry in an HTTP get request.
In the body, you see a script tag with a function call where I need to have access to the JSON inside the HTML tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html translate="no">

<head></head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(function() {
          intranet.list.frontend.init({
              gridDataAndConfiguration: {
                "Here is a big Json - WANTED"
              },
            },
          });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Up to now, I don't parse the HTML with any Dart specific parsing method like
"parse" from `package:html/parser.dart`. That attempt was successful in searching for all the "script" tags inside the HTML DOM, but unfortunately, I did not find or showed the JSON or function call inside the referred script Tag!

The question is, how to access the JSON in the given HTML Page using Dart?

Solution :

```
RegExp re = RegExp(r'\[\{.*?\}\]');
var parsedHtml = parse(htmlText);
var allScripts = parsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (int i = 0; i < allScripts.length; i++) {
  if (allScripts[i].innerHtml.contains(startString)) {
    Iterable<String> result =
        re.allMatches(allScripts[i].innerHtml).map((m) => m[0]);
    List<dynamic> jsonParsed = [];
    for (var match in result) jsonParsed.add(jsonDecode(match));
```

Thanks for your answer & help.

Comment: I you could get the content of the script tag using the `html` package and then use a regex to get the JSON content.

Comment: Hello @croxx5f, thanks for your suggestion. If I have the List<Element> with all the script tags, how would I know which one is the correct one? How would I access the entire string inside the tag?

Comment: Hmm I was assuming from your example that the response only contained one script tag. As for accesing the content of the tag you can use `innerHtml`. Assuming that the structure of the js inside your example tag is not volatile I would probably iterate all the tags `innerHtml` and try to match its content via regex. Not pretty but , it could get the job done